# #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors

Tags: maven, jetbrains-ide

I can't use my maven to import any dependencies.
It hinted "Unable to import maven project: See logs for details" when I used it.

> #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1. No implementation for org.apache.maven.model.path.PathTranslator
>    was bound.
>    while locating org.apache.maven.model.path.PathTranslator
>    for field at
>
> org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.AbstractStringBasedModelInterpolator.pathTranslator(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$1.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:350)
>
> 2. No implementation for org.apache.maven.model.path.UrlNormalizer was
>    bound.   while locating org.apache.maven.model.path.UrlNormalizer
>    for field at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.AbstractStringBasedModelInterpolator.urlNormalizer(Unknown
>    Source)   at
>    org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$1.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:350)

Answer (score 2):

I observed this with Idea 2019.1.3 after upgrading maven 3.2.5 to 3.6.3. Solved by downgrading maven version.

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade to latest 3.5 version [Maven 3.5.4](https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.5.4/)